# how cofigure simple chat widget in yii2

Tags: yii2

I have  installed simple chat widget in my application through composer . then I made its configuration .
as I am new to yii2 unable to understad how to do its cofiguration in console application ?

I am following the steps on http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-simplechat/#hh0

when reach for the step to `**You can access Simple Chat via command line as follows:**` how to follow this step from above link..??

get error when i run this command `php yii simplechat`

```
Exception 'yii\base\InvalidConfigException' with message 'The configuration for
the "user" component must contain a "class" element.'

in C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2-my-chat\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\ServiceLocator.php:204

Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2-my-chat\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\ServiceLocator.php(260):
yii\di\ServiceLocator->set('user', Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2-my-chat\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Component.php(172): yii
\di\ServiceLocator->setComponents(Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2-my-chat\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\BaseYii.php(529): yii\base\C
omponent->__set('components', Array)
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2-my-chat\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Object.php(105): yii\Ba
seYii::configure(Object(yii\console\Application), Array)
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2-my-chat\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(205): y
ii\base\Object->__construct(Array)
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2-my-chat\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\console\Application.php(89):
 yii\base\Application->__construct(Array)
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2-my-chat\yii(26): yii\console\Application->__construct(Ar
ray)
#7 {main}
```

can any one tell me how to step by integrate simple chat??

here is code frontend/config/main.php

```
return[ 'bootstrap' => ['log','simplechat'],
    'modules' => [
        'simplechat' => [
            'class' => 'bubasuma\simplechat\Module',
        ],];
```

what changes should I make?

Answer (score 0):

I checked you had setup the module into your frontend config, try to put it in your common config `common\config\main.php` and then try the command.

If you are using yii2-advanced-app then remember to put changes of config always in environments directory and then run init command `php init`